# Test class for Transaction Finalizer is not working

Tags: apex, failing-tests, queueable-apex, queueable, transaction-finalizers

I am stuck in the test class for the Transaction Finalizer class. Every time when we create an exception for Queueable class then Finalizer class executing and then the test class throws the error on the test method and also not handled by try catch.

Below is my Queueable class Sample code:

```
public class QueueableClass implements Queueable {

    public void execute (QueueableContext context) {

    QueueableFinalizer finalizer = new QueueableFinalizer();
    System.attachFinalizer(finalizer);

   // Below code will failed Queueable because of System.LimitException: Too many DML 
   // statements: 151 And then Finalizer class will be Executes.

     if(Test.isRunningTest()){

     while (true) { // results in limit error
            Account a = new Account();
            a.Name = 'Account-Number-';
            insert a;
        }
         }
           }
```

Below is my Finalizer class Sample code:

```
   public class QueueableFinalizer implements Finalizer{

         public void execute(FinalizerContext ctx) { 
    
    // here we rerun the Queueable by using the system.Queueable
            
}
}
```

Below is my Test class Sample code for Finalizer:

```
   public static testMethod void testToFailQueueable() {

   test.startTest();
    try{
        System.enqueueJob(new QueueableClass ());  // here Too many DML Statement Error Occur.
        
    }catch(Exception e){
        
    }
    test.stopTest();
         
  
  }
```

Please suggest to me how to implement the test class for Finalizer. Thank you!

Comment: Since you can rely on the infrastructure to function correctly - there really isn't a need to unit test this - you could instead simply and explicitly test the finaliser implementation behaviour using an explicit call to its execute method from a separate test. BTW by separating out the finaliser into a separate class, instead of having a class that impleme to both the quueable and finaliser, you lose access to the queueable's state. Additionally the keyword `testMethod` is deprecated, replaced years ago by `@isTest`.

Comment: (My guess is that the test infrastructure doesn't handle governor limit issues and finalizers properly. This would not be the first bug in the testing infrastructure around async processing)

Comment: @Philw Yeah we can explicitly call to its execute method from a separate test but it doesn't test our Finalizer requirement. We want to Assert the First and last Error from the finalizer.

Answer (score 4):

Since Async operations run in Sync manner inside `test.startTest` and `test.stopTest()`.

You wont be able to capture `LimitException` with a try catch.

No need to test unhandled exceptions from test class. In documentation its mentioned that no matter what happens `Finalizer` will get called. So you can rest assure that it will get called.

Better throw a `DML Exception` when a test is running and test finalizer as `LimitExceptions` cannot be caught.

Test Class:

```
@IsTest
static void testLimitFinalizer() {
    try {
        Test.startTest();
        System.enqueueJob(new QueueableClassLimit());
        Test.stopTest();
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.debug(e);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class QueueableClassLimit implements Queueable {

    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {

        QueueableFinalizer finalizer = new QueueableFinalizer();
        System.attachFinalizer(finalizer);

        // Below code will failed Queueable because of System.LimitException: Too many DML
        // statements: 151 And then Finalizer class will be Executes.

        if (Test.isRunningTest()) {

            throw new DmlException('Test My Finalizer');
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class QueueableFinalizer implements Finalizer{

    public void execute(FinalizerContext ctx) {

        System.debug('Test Finalizer');

    }
}
```

Test class passes:

[image]

Comment: You make a good point, actually.

Comment: The finalizer execution should still happen when the limit error is thrown, though it must be said the limit exception still terminates the original transaction so, yeah, the exception should still happen and, yeah, use a cashable exception in this (integration) testing context.

Comment: Yes correct, finalizer will execute even from test context.

Comment: I added the below DML Exception code in Queueable class:

if(test.isRunningTest()){
            Account a = new Account();
            insert a;
        }

But still, the exception is thrown on the test method.

test.startTest();
        try{
            System.enqueueJob(new OpportunityCloseQueueable(testOppUpdateMap, testOppList));  
        }catch(Exception e){
            
        }
        test.stopTest();

Comment: Again as suggested by @sfdcfox you will have to put your try catch differently. See my above example.

Comment: Now the DMLException Error thrown from Queueable class but test class Try catch didn't able to handle the Exception.

Comment: I am not sure how have you written the code, but I ran the test class and it catches the thrown exception from queueable.

Comment: We both have the same code, just I have re-enqueue the Queueable job in the Finalizer class.
System.enqueueJob(new QueueableClass ());

By following your above code sample, I have noticed that test Execution is passing but DMLException Error shown in the debug log. And by using the re enqueue in Finalizer class, the test execution is failed.

Comment: From a test context you can only call one enqueue job, so dont chain enqueujob from test methods.  Its mentioned in docs.

`You can’t chain queueable jobs in an Apex test. Doing so results in an error. To avoid getting an error, you can check if Apex is running in test context by calling Test.isRunningTest() before chaining jobs.`

Comment: Our requirement is to assert the first and last Error log of the finalizer. But when we check the test.isrunningtest before chaining jobs, always my Error log record size will be 1. I think this test assertion will not be possible because test context only allow for one queueable job.