# How do I unit test a TransactionFinalizer?

Tags: transaction-finalizers

I have a transaction finalizer (attached by my queueable) that I need to unit test. It looks like this (simplified)

```
public class MyTransactionFinalizer implements System.Finalizer {
  public void execute(System.FinalizerContext fc) {
   if (fc.getResult() == ParentJobResult.SUCCESS) {
      // do success stuff 
   }
   if (fc.getResult() == ParentJobResult.UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION) {
      // do fail stuff
   }
  }
}
```

How do I test the success versus fail paths?

Getting the queueable to throw a Limits exception [doesn't work as per this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/365995/2602) and [this discussion initiated by Dan Appleman](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A6kKtSAJ) on the Transaction Finalizers community

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The secret is to realize that `System.FinalizerContext` is an *interface* and thus you can, at unit test time, provide a mock implementation of that interface.

Here's the unit test class:

```
private class TransactionFinalizerTest {
 
 /** Mock FinalizerContext impl **/
 class MockFinalizerContext implements System.FinalizerContext {
    ParentJobResult result;
    public Id getAsyncApexJobId() { // valid Id, or query one 
         return '707000000000000';
    }
    public Exception getException() { return new System.AsyncException('heap breached'); }
    public String getRequestId() { return 'someRequestId'; }
    public ParentJobResult getResult() { return this.result; }
    MockFinalizerContext (ParentJobResult mockResult) {this.result = mockResult;}
 }

 @IsTest
 static void givenSuccessVerifyFinalizer() {
    // Given Finalizer
    MyTransactionFinalizer finalizer = new MyTransactionFinalizer();
    // When finalizer invoked by SFDC as success
    finalizer.execute(new MockFinalizerContext(ParentJobResult.SUCCESS));
    // Then verify ...
    ... asserts here
 }

 @IsTest
 static void givenUnhandledExceptionVerifyFinalizer() {
    // Given Finalizer
    MyTransactionFinalizer finalizer = new MyTransactionFinalizer();
    // When finalizer invoked by SFDC as unhandled exception
    finalizer.execute(new MockFinalizerContext(ParentJobResult.UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION));
    // Then verify ...
    ... asserts here
 }
```

Note that this approach can also be used for unit testing:

- Schedulable - by providing a mock implementation of [System.SchedulableContext](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_interface_system_schedulablecontext.htm)
- Batchable - by providing a mock implementation of [Database.BatchableContext](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_interface_database_batchablecontext.htm)
- Queuable - by providing a mock implementation of [System.QueuableContext](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_interface_system_queueablecontext.htm)
- and many more where SFDC passes an object implementing an interface to your Apex

***Illuminated Cloud IDE users:***

*You'll need version 2.2.3.4+ and regenerate your OST to allow the System.FinalizerContext to be recognized as an interface rather than as a class.*

Comment: One problem though, you are invoking the non static method from the static test method, it won't even compile.

Comment: Super useful, thanks a lot cropredy!

Comment: @TonyWong - I'm confused about this remark -- which line won't compile?  The test method creates a TransactionFinalizer object and passes the mock FinalizerContext object to it. It should (and does) work fine