# Apex Schedule Test Class Code Coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test, scheduled-apex

How Can I test the below class?

```java
public class SaleItem implements Schedulable {
    public void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        SaleProduct.pollSae('MT');        
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The literal and boring answer is "the same way you test any other code".

- Set up test data
- Call your method
- Gather results and make assertions

The `execute()` method is still a method, and you can call it as if it were any other method.

```java
SaleItem instance = new SaleItem();
instance.execute(null);
```

Passing null in for the `SchedulableContext` is fine as long as you don't need/use the ScheduleableContext (and most people don't use it).

Not going through the apex scheduler is also fine. You have no control over the scheduler (other than forcing async code to run after `Test.stopTest();`), so you shouldn't try to test it. Your concern here is testing the code that *you* have written and have control over.

Comment: N.B. for others coming to this answer, should your execute actually need to operate on the SchedulableContext variable `sc`, you can mock this using the [pattern here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/384421/2602)